# Faster compilation for Haskell Miso

Tags: haskell, compilation, nix, ghcjs, haskell-miso

I use the Haskell Miso framework to write frontend web apps and [the Nix compilation process](https://github.com/haskell-miso/miso#nix) takes a long time.

How can I speed it up?

Or what is the recommended approach to have a near instantaneous edit-compile-run cycle?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

(Credit goes to [NickSeagull](https://github.com/NickSeagull))

For faster edit-compile-run cycle it is recommended to use `GHCJSi` as follows.

First, enter the Nix configured shell environment:

```
nix-shell -A env
```

Then, enter the GHCJSi shell:

```
cabal configure --ghcjs
cabal repl
```

GHCJSi starts up a web server. You should immediately connect to it from the web browser via http://localhost:6400/

From the GHCJSi shell--and everytime `Main.hs` changes--recompile and send the new code to the browser:

```
> import Miso.Dev  # Once
> :r
> clearBody >> main
```

The UI in the web browser will now update automatically with the new code. Happy hacking!

[Example project](https://github.com/srid/miso-viso#development)